# Rails 4 - whitelisted nested attributes nil in create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`admin_params` is a hash for permitted attributes in Rails 4.2 (see below):

[image]

Here is the controller action `create`:

```
def create
      @user = User.new(admin_params)
      @user.last_updated_by_id = session[:user_id]
      if @user.save
        redirect_to URI.escape(SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=0&msg=Successfully Saved!")
      else
        flash.now[:error] = t('Data Error. Not Saved!')
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

Both nested attributes `sys_user_group_id` and `role_definition_id` are expected to be equal to 1 in `@user`. However both of them become `nil` after `@user = User.new(admin_params)`. Somehow `admin_params` did not pass the value of `role_definition_id` and `sys_user_group_id` to `@user` (other non-nested values passes in to `@user` successfully except 2 nested).

The `admin_params` is defined as:

```
def admin_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :login, :email, :update_password_checkbox, :password_confirmation,
                                   :password_new,  :status, :user_type_id, :cell, :allow_text_msg,
                                    :allow_email, :password, :customer_id, :customer_name, :local, user_roles_attributes: [:id, :role_definition_id, :_destroy],
                                    user_levels_attributes: [:id, :sys_user_group_id, :_destroy])                              
    end
```

[Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) is rails document we are following about strong parameters of nested attributes. What could cause @user not being assigned for 2 nested attributes? Could be the data structure of `admin_params`?

Comment: Where in the app is that populated params hash from?  (and what did you use to view it?)

Comment: It is in rspec the params hash gets populated.

Comment: And it's only those two attributes that become `nil`?

Comment: `@rainbowsorbet `, yes, only 2 nested attributes nil.

Comment: A dumb mistake! There are still `attr_accessible` in 2 nested models which causes nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming of these attributes may be inconsistent, which would cause the behavior you're observing.

`user_role_id` does not appear in your list of arguments to #permit. Perhaps that's due to some rails syntactic sugar I don't yet know, given that `:id` is a value in the `user_roles_attributes` array.  But in that case, I would expect `sys_user_group_id` (which does an argument to #permit) to be `user_levels_sys_user_group_id`, because `:sys_user_group_id` appears in the `user_levels_attributes` array.